# How to check which hypervisor is used from my VM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, kvm

So I'm running a VM somewhere and want to know what hypervisor the host is running. Any way to check whether it's running KVM or in a container?

The vm is running Ubuntu

Comment: This question should be removed because is a duplicate of the one above, which is more precise and with far more detailed responses.

Answer (score 22):

Without external tools:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -i -e manufacturer -e product -e vendor
```

or

```
sudo grep -i -e virtual -e vbox -e xen /var/log/dmesg  # or /var/log/kern.log
```

should give you enough to go on.

You can see checks for specific platforms in the [ImVirt module](https://github.com/DE-IBH/imvirt/tree/1d625211e60ea1c797670c3d2f909aa198f07404/perl/lib/ImVirt/VMD).

Comment: This doesn't work, at least for xen. It shows the platform's specifications even in a vm.

Answer (score 15):

Look at `virt-what`

```
stephenm@pc:~$ apt-cache search virt-what
virt-what - detect if we are running in a virtual machine
```

`sudo apt-get install virt-what`

`sudo virt-what`

Comment: This is how `facter` (puppet) determines the VM type.

Comment: Simple and concise, this is the best answer for me.